# Relay - dataID.startsWith is not a function

Tags: graphql, relayjs

I'm playing around graphQL and relay, I make backend in .NET [using graphQL-dotnet](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet)

I have problem with client, I send my query using relay as I see in dev tools client receive all data and nothing happened, just receive warning in console:

> dataID.startsWith is not a function

This issue occurse when I trying to get data in schema like:

```
ListOfItems{
  listProp{
    itemName
  }
}
```

where `listProp` is `ListGraphType`

When I trying to ask about diffrent data that is not a List It working fine.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you show your schema?

Comment: I resolved this issue by adding Field Id like Id(x=>x.id).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id` should be a `string`, not an `int`.

Specifically, the GraphQL server may represent the value of id as any scalar type, but it should serialize to/from a string. This is the case by default if you're using graphql-relay-js, so perhaps this is an issue with how you configured the schema.